# Is YouTube earning halal?

Tags: halal-haram, work, internet

Is earning money through YouTube halal?

I play video games and upload that content on YouTube. So is YouTube earning halal in islam?

Comment: It is halal as long as the video content does not show or encourage anything haram.

Comment: Nice comment @Zohel, but on the other hand, what about this point that: if: it led to be encountered with haram scenes (pics,movies...) accidentally? (if it is ineludible?)?

Comment: Some more points to consider: What if the youtube engineers who create algorithms (which promote your video) and maintain data servers are consuming alcohol while doing so? There are also alcohol cooling in data servers. Can data being hosted on a machine built or sustained using alcohol be halal? The facebook movie also shows they made a lot of software while being drunk to avoid being caught by law. Is fb halal?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is halal as there is nothing wrong with recording video games and making walk-throughs, tutorials or anything like that. And many muslims do make their earnings through YouTube.

But make sure to censor any abusive content or any scenes like that. As many modern games contain stuff like that and it is a sin to spread bad things.