# Earning money online from youtube

Tags: halal-haram

is it halal earning money from Youtube and if i post Gameplay of shooting games is it halal games like pubg and is it halal to earn money from Youtube from only views

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not fully certain on what does the word Halal and Haram mean. But I will tell you that, what do you think? Do you think it is right to post. There is nothing wrong with posting and playing video games but it can also be taken the wrong direction.

For Example: You can use a knife the right way and cut an Apple, or use it the wrong way and cut yourself.

Check these posts out:

[Is YouTube earning halal?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28121/is-youtube-earning-halal?r=SearchResults)

[Is killing people in video games haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/52213/is-killing-people-in-video-games-haram?r=SearchResults)

Note: I am not a scholar.